# Server Error : The server closed the connection while reading the response

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have windows xp and iis installed , when I want to access localhost to view asp pages , I get the following error :

Server Error
The following error occurred:

[code=SERVER_RESPONSE_CLOSE] The server closed the connection while reading the response. Contact your system administrator.
Please contact the administrator

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

There's a few causes of this, including a corrupt IIS metabase (which basically means you need to remove the \inetsrv folder from your PC and reinstall IIS).

Most likely is that you have more than 10 connections open to your local IIS at one time. To support more you'll need to use a server operating system such as Windows Server 2003.